# jQuery dialog with asp.net control loosing viewstate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog, postback

I have a form that required some of the fields to be field out in a jQuery dialog (for example, a contact's name and last name are filled out in the dialog and then populated as a concatenated string in the base form).

Whenever I need to use the dialog for a different set of fields (let's say for the address), and the second dialog required postback, the fields in the first dialog loose their viewstate.

I am using the following code to instantiate the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.FadingDialogNoButtons').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'dialog_xms',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        close: false,
        dragabble: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        width: 300,
        position: ['middle','middle'],

        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo('form');
        },
    });
});
```

And the following code to open de dialogs:

```
function FadingDialogOpen(vDivId, vWidth, vShowOk, vShowCancel) {
    $('#' + vDivId).dialog("open");
    if (vWidth == null) { vWidth = 300 };
    $('#' + vDivId).dialog("option", "width", vWidth);
    if (vShowOk != 'True') { $('#FadingDlgOkButton').hide(); }
    if (vShowCancel != 'True') { $('#FadingDlgCancelButton').hide(); }
    return false;
};
```

And this is an example of the div that goes inside the dialog:

```
<div id="dlgActividadesDelProyecto" class="FadingDialogNoButtons" title="Actividades del proyecto" data-iddiv="dlgActividadesDelProyecto" style="display: none">
    <div class="grid" style="font-size: 10pt;">
        <asp:Panel CssClass="row no-margin" ID="Panel10" runat="server">
            <div class="span8 no-margin fieldContainer">
                <label class="span2 requiredField">Actividad</label>
                <div class="input-control text span3 errorPlaceholder">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dlgTxtActividadesDelProyectoNombre" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                    <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span8 no-margin fieldContainer">
                <label class="span2 requiredField">Etapa</label>
                <div class="input-control text span3 errorPlaceholder">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dlgTxtActividadesDelProyectoEtapa" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                    <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, this is the code triggered after the event that should fire up the dialog:

```
function actividadesDelProyectoAdd() {
    var a = 1;
    $("#<%=dlgTxtActividadesDelProyectoNombre.ClientID%>").val("");
    $("#<%=dlgTxtActividadesDelProyectoEtapa.ClientID%>").val("");
    $("#<%=dlgDdlActividadesDelProyectoMesDeCumplimientoMes.ClientID%>").val("0");
    $("#<%=dlgDdlActividadesDelProyectoMesDeCumplimientoAno.ClientID%>").val("0");
    $('.FadingDialogNoButtons').dialog();
    FadingDialogOpen("dlgActividadesDelProyecto", 651);
    return false;
}
```

All of this is working just fine, except when I need to open a second dialog (after the first one has closed). Whenever the second dialog causes a postback, I loose the state values for the `asp:textboxes` in the first dialog.

Here is an example of a Page_Load event code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If Not ptyMembershipUser.AccountIsMunicipalidad Then
            ShowErrorDialogWithReturnToDefault("error!", "Usted no está autorizado para llenar esta solicitud!")
            Return
        End If
        Using apiCampaigns As New xmsbs.xrm.crud.bllXrmCampaigns
            If Not _demoMode AndAlso Not apiCampaigns.getCampaignState_For_ProyectosMunicipales Then
                Response.Redirect("~/postulacionesCerradas.aspx?id=proyectos municipales")
            End If
        End Using

        fillForm()
        hdnStepNumber.Value = enumWizardStep.SelectMunicipalidad
        If _demoMode Then fillDemoData()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards, Ariel

Comment: Do you have any code in your CodeBehind, PageLoad or something?

Comment: Yes, there is lot's of code behind for the Page_Load and crud operations. But as far as I know, none of them "clear" out the textboxes filled out in the dialogs. I added and example of the Page_Load event to the original question.